# Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, program-entry-point

I am getting this error as a result on my code.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class car{
public static void main(String[]args) throws java.io.IOException{
Scanner v = new Scanner(System.in);

String model = new String(); 
double cost=0;

System.out.print("Enter model: ");
model = System.console().readLine();

if(model == "GL"){
    cost = 420000;
    }

if (model == "XL"){
    cost = 3398000;
    }






System.out.print("Car phone: ");
char phone = (char)System.in.read();

if(phone == 'W'){
cost = cost + 40000;
}

System.out.print("Full or installment: ");
char paid = (char)System.in.read();

if(paid == 'F'){
cost = cost - 0.15 * cost;
}

System.out.print("Cost: " + cost); 

}
}
```

and this is the result. An error:
Enter model: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at car.main(car.java:10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the following line:

```
model = System.console().readLine();
```

At the time you’re calling readLine(), the System.console() is null - hence why you get a NullPointerException. All you need to do is use the Scanner.nextLine() method, i.e. replacing this line with:

```
model = v.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 3):

You have already defined Scanner object. Use the instance of Scanner object and set the value for model. Instead of doing System.console() you can try v.next()

```
import java.util.*;

public class car {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        Scanner v = new Scanner(System.in);

        String model = new String();
        double cost = 0;

        System.out.print("Enter model: ");
        //model = System.console().readLine();
        model = v.next();

        if (model == "GL") {
            cost = 420000;
        }

        if (model == "XL") {
            cost = 3398000;
        }

        System.out.print("Car phone: ");
        char phone = (char) System.in.read();

        if (phone == 'W') {
            cost = cost + 40000;
        }

        System.out.print("Full or installment: ");
        char paid = (char) System.in.read();

        if (paid == 'F') {
            cost = cost - 0.15 * cost;
        }

        System.out.print("Cost: " + cost);

    }
}
```

Output :

```
Enter model: GL
Car phone: W
Full or installment: Cost: 40000.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much!   model = v.next(); worked. But i didn't get the output that I desired but I can handle it now. Thank you thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is null:

```
System.console()
```

So calling readLine() on it means calling a method on null.

You may want to use a Scanner on System.in instead, for I/O.

Answer (score -1):

`System.console()` can return null. see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console())

when you are running java program through IDE, then console will not be available, in such cases `System.console()` returns `null`. when java program is run from termainl, then `System.console()` does not return `null`

so it is always best practice to check for `null`

Comment: The answer explains the reason for the problem, but could be expanded by giving the user some guidance on how to fix it...